# How to make React and Typescript to allow either base set of properties or an extended one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React wrapper component that renders specific components based on "variant" prop. There are basic component and two others that extend props of the basic one. Union type is not working. Here is the code of the wrapper component:

```
type Props = 
  | ({ variant: "first" } & FirstComponentProps) }
  | ({ variant: "second" } & SecondComponentProps)
  | BaseComponentProps);

export default function WrapperComponent(props: Props) {
  switch (props.variant) {
    case "first":
      return <FirstComponent {...props} />
    case "second":
      return <SecondComponent {...props} />
    default:
      return <BaseComponent {...props} />
  }
}
```

Types for these components:

```
type BaseComponentProps = { propA: string; }
type FirstComponentProps = { propB: string } & BaseComponentProps
type SecondComponentProps = { propC: string } & BaseComponentProps
```

And here how this wrapper component can be used:

```
<WrapperComponent variant="first" propA="value" propB="value" />
<WrapperComponent variant="second" propA="value" propC="value" />
<WrapperComponent propA="value" />
```

This should trigger typescript warnings:

```
<WrapperComponent propA="value" propB="value" />
```

How to properly type the wrapper component props so that it allows only correct combinations of props?

Thank you!

Comment: use interface instead

Answer (score 1):

There's tricky solution:

```js
type Props =
  | ({ variant: "first" } & FirstComponentProps)
  | ({ variant: "second" } & SecondComponentProps)
  | ({ variant?: void } & { [key in Exclude<keyof (FirstComponentProps & SecondComponentProps), keyof BaseComponentProps>]?: void } & BaseComponentProps);
```

Playground result [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAIRQGckBhXSAOyQ5gAUcwjOAF44AbzhgBAQQBccRjCjAOAcwDccAL4VqtAGLAoituAhce-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-HgJ0OlI8tj8cT17a0mEcMhpVGSAomOXqvnGCZIEm-Zfj+f4ASibR0DBKD-oBu6DCBb7gZB+o8PY1jfr+yFwXhYAsEhKFAehL6YR+-ZlkSP4NsiJEEbBqHAdRYG0Th8D0TwjFIjA8EyORxEIaJ7FUaB74QdefEwAJjYsRJwmpCpaEYVxsl0YS-FwqS0SqWArFEZJmkydh67MrpCn6TOURGSZFEkYhhHORx0lYXJNk-gZs7KW5YkCGRgVmaQQA)

**How it works?**

Due to [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), your `BaseComponentProps` allowed other variant's property, but it is treated as `BaseComponentProps`, so no any warning triggered.

Let variant's props to be `void` can warn you shouldn't put variant's props because that type is `void`.

Or use generic component:

```js
type WrapperComponentProps<T extends 'first' | 'second' | '_base' = '_base'> =
  T extends '_base'
  ? { variant?: void } & BaseComponentProps
  : { variant: T } & ({
    'first': FirstComponentProps,
    'second': SecondComponentProps,
  }[Exclude<T, '_base'>]);

export default function WrapperComponent<T extends 'first' | 'second' | '_base' = '_base'>(props: WrapperComponentProps<T>) {
  switch (props.variant) {
    case "first":
      return <FirstComponent {...props} />
    case "second":
      return <SecondComponent {...props} />
    default:
      return <BaseComponent {...props} />
  }
}
```

Playground result [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOAIRQGckBhXSAOyQ5gAUcwjOAF44AbzhgBAQQBccRjCjAOAcwDccAL4VqtAGLAoituAhce-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-WWjgAHpBrP5wvcdFV+u4Jvt7vwU8HUexCex2fL9eGQZWN41KJonxfHc906E1j1PQJzyvLkdB0UhwQzRtm26fx7GsaRhAXAVSlGJAF3-cM0IbLMjzaPCCJQIiSJwsA6HwwjiNIq9yPQqisJ4JjaLYxi2hYVj6PYsjUO4psYMnNV8OXGBSJo0SGI4wYuMo6Sj1knh5P1JSZBU8S2hYujVIkijMy03j4B0mA9KWAzcKMoSBBEszxM4yTNMwuVbMFOS73tKInLAASxMYrzLIwmSAt0oLrlC8LzJMly1I0qzfIKfzVXi+9WSStKmPcwT0tIIA)

This one will restrict props type by condition (default is `BaseComponentProps`).